# LWC Dual list box setting the value getting Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.value.forEach is not a function

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, salesforce1-app, lightning-duallistbox

Trying to set dual list box value getting below error `**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.value.forEach is not a function at ie.get computedSelectedList [as computedSelectedList]**`

**HTML**

```
<div class="tableInfo" style="overflow-x:auto;">
   <table
      class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered">
      <thead>
         <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
            <th class="" scope="col">
               <div class="slds-truncate" title="">
               </div>
            </th>
            <th class="" scope="col">
               <div class="slds-truncate" title="Rule">
                  Rule
               </div>
            </th>
            <th class="" scope="col">
               <div class="slds-truncate" title="Rule">
                  Notification Type
               </div>
            </th>
            <th class="" scope="col">
               <div class="slds-truncate" title="">
               </div>
            </th>
            <th class="" scope="col">
               <div class="slds-truncate" title=" ">
               </div>
            </th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <template for:each={getSchedulerDetails} for:item="it"
            for:index="index">
            <tr key={it.recId} class="slds-hint-parent">
               <td data-label={it.rowNum} scope="row">
                  <div class="slds-truncate"
                     title={it.rowNum}>
                     {it.rowNum}
                  </div>
               </td>
               <td data-label={it.rule} scope="row">
                  <div class="slds-truncate" title={it.rule}>
                     {it.rule}
                  </div>
               </td>
               <td data-label={it.rule} scope="row">
                  <div class="slds-truncate" title={it.rule}>
                     {it.notificationType}
                  </div>
               </td>
               <td scope="row">
                  <div class="slds-truncate">
                     <lightning-button-icon
                        data-id={it.recId}
                        data-schedulertype={it.schedulerType}
                        data-schedulerdate={it.schedulerDate}
                        data-schedulerwhen={it.schedulerWhen}
                        data-noofdate={it.noOfDate}
                        data-notificationtype={it.notificationType}
                        icon-name="utility:edit"
                        variant="brand"
                        alternative-text="edit"
                        onclick={handleonclickEditRuleModal}>
                     </lightning-button-icon>
                  </div>
               </td>
               <td scope="row">
                  <div class="slds-truncate">
                     <lightning-button-icon
                        icon-name="utility:delete"
                        data-id={it.recId} variant="brand"
                        alternative-text="delete"
                        onclick={handleonclickDeleteRuleModal}>
                     </lightning-button-icon>
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </template>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
handleonclickEditRuleModal(event) {
this.selectNotificationType = event.currentTarget.dataset.notificationtype;
        console.log(this.selectNotificationType);
}
```

Trying to add `selectNotificationType` value in the below dual listbox

```
<lightning-dual-listbox id="selectOptions" name="Select Options" label=" "
                                            source-label="Notification Types"
                                            selected-label="Selected Notification Types" value={selectNotificationType}
                                            options={notificationTypesOptions} onchange={handleChangeDualPicklist}>
                                        </lightning-dual-listbox>
```

**APEX**

```
    List <String> ptlist = new list <string>();
            if(sch.emitcs2__Notification_Type__c !=null){
                List<String> lstnotf = sch.emitcs2__Notification_Type__c.split(';');                
                for(string pt: lstnotf ){
                    system.debug('pt' + pt);
                    ptlist.add(pt);
                }                 
                wrapper.notificationType = ptlist;
            }
```

Can you please help what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the data to load. Something like this:

```
<lightning-dual-listbox if:true={selectNotificationType} ...
```

Comment: Still getting same Error `<lightning-dual-listbox id="selectOptions" if:true={selectNotificationType}
                                            name="Select Options" label=" " source-label="Notification Types"
                                            selected-label="Selected Notification Types" value={selectNotificationType}
                                            options={notificationTypesOptions} onchange={handleChangeDualPicklist}>
                                        </lightning-dual-listbox>`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error.
Issue in my case was that the value was incorrect type as it was string instead of array. You should make sure that the variable that assign is an array

```
value={selectNotificationType}
```